# No such module PDFReader

Tags: pdf, cocoapods

so i try to install PDF Reader. https://cocoapods.org/pods/PDFReader in installation guide i follow the instruction

```
target 'thePDF' do
    pod 'PDFReader', '~> 2.1'
end
```

after pod install
[image]

i try so many option like only `pod 'PDFReader'` or try different version but still doesn't work.

**EDIT:**
i try

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, ‘8.0’
use_frameworks!
target ‘thePDF’ do
pod 'PDFReader', :git => 'https://github.com/Alua-Kinzhebayeva/iOS-  PDF-Reader.git'
end
```

and it works, but when build, it shows some errors
[image]

Comment: To remove the error "Your Podfile has had smart quotes sanitized.", see there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31832538/error-using-pod-install-command-on-podfile-in-terminal. You are using `‘` instead of `'` for the iOS version and the target. And with only `pod 'PDFReader'`, it doesn't work?

Comment: i turned off smart quotes, and still deosn't work